# How can I Merge two JavaScript objects?

Tags: javascript

I have two JavaScript objects

```
a =  {"aa" : "foo"}
b = {"b" : "bar"}
```

I want to concat both and want to get this result

```
result =  {"aa" : "foo" , "b" :"bar"}
```

what is the simplest way to do this in plain javascript. I am not using any external libraries like jquery or underscore.

Comment: There's no such thing as a "json object".

Comment: check this : https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign

Comment: Please search SO before asking your question, this has been asked before.

Comment: many, many, many times before

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `Object.assign`, here is the [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign).

```
var mergedObject = Object.assign(a, b);
```

Be aware that `Object.assign` will merge from left to right so any keys that are the same will be overridden if added later in the parameter list.

Comment: This will change `a`.

Comment: `Object.assign({}, a, b)` is how you should do it if you don't want to mutate your original objects.

Answer (score 2):

```
var o1 = {"aa" : "foo" };
var o2 = { "b" : "bar" };

var obj = Object.assign(o1, o2);
```

Answer (score 2):

Ideally, as suggested in the previous two answers, using `Object.assign` is your best bet, unless browser support dictates otherwise, although, the [MDN documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign) provides an ES5 polyfill.

```
if (typeof Object.assign != 'function') {
  Object.assign = function(target) {
    'use strict';
    if (target == null) {
      throw new TypeError('Cannot convert undefined or null to object');
    }

    target = Object(target);
    for (var index = 1; index < arguments.length; index++) {
      var source = arguments[index];
      if (source != null) {
        for (var key in source) {
          if (Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(source, key)) {
            target[key] = source[key];
          }
        }
      }
    }
    return target;
  };
}
```

Comment: his tag is only javascript no Jquery

Comment: You can check the updated Javascript solution @gayathri